# Searching for hex nut for spindle pedal

Tags: pedals

2 months ago  I bought a pair pedals of VP Components VP-007. They stared squeaking when rotating. I've opened them to see what going inside, a lot of grease was accumulated at one place and spread it across the spindle fixed first pedal. The second have problems with the hex nut holding the spindle. It's a reverse threads and they were damaged (It was rotating at one place). After carefully pushing and pulling the spindle the hex nut comes out. I went to local bike shops, services, hardware stores, but they didn't find exact the same hex nut.

I've contacted the local shop where I bought the pedals showing photos and explaining the situation - they didn't help. Also the manufacturer VP Components told me that they never had such model `VP-007` and it's possible to be a fake product *(I also showed them pictures of the pedals)*.

Why I'm writing this whole story, because one hex nut with price not more than a dollar fu*ked up a pedal with price around $80 *(which is quite expensive for me)*.

**And I'm searching for that da*n hex nut.** I can't provide the exact specifics for the hex nut, but it seems to respond on M6 *(size here is a chart https://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/server300/9376c/products/14718/images/14557/692824__37617.1489405294.1280.1280.jpg?c=2)*

So far I found:

- [Spindle from AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32788303310.html), but they didn't sell the nut separatly

  - A lot of results comes out for M6 nut, but can anyone fit ¯\*(ツ)*/¯
- https://chromagbikes.com/products/pedal-axle-kit
- not sure whether they sell only the hexagons (maybe I could ask them, but the delivery will be something like $20 )

Here are some images
[image: The pedal components]
[image: Spindle and nut]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need a left-hand thread nut, and possibly a locknut to suit the thread pitch on your spindle, whatever that may be.

Buying nuts and bolts at a retail shop is expensive, and they generally have only standard sizes. Since you need a reverse/left hand thread you're already out of their league.

I've had excellent results using a specialist nut/bolt supplier.  Downside is they tend to deal in wholesale quantities, and one-off are often "beneath" them.  The trick is to do as much pre-work as possible, and present it as a "challenge"

Google up "how to measure a thread" and use a micrometer or at least calipers to get exact measurements.  You'll need to figure out the thread pitch too, which means a thread gauge in metric and imperial, or some very careful counting to get a "Turns Per Inch" or metric equivalent.

---

If the bolt shop can't help, you might need to get one made.  Downside, the commercial rate on hand-made parts could exceed the replacement cost of the pedal.

So try for a hobbiest machinist.  Making a nut is straight forward especially if the right size of hex-stock is available.  The problem comes in finding a left-handed tap of exactly the specs you need.

Or your machinist might choose to single-point cut the thread, which needs a thread-cutting lathe and a particularly small boring bar.

---

There may be a bike cooperative who has spare pedals and parts etc in bins.  Ask around and see if there's anything like that in your area.

---

Ultimately your worst case is a replacement pedal.

Comment: tangential story - I needed some tiny grub screws to fix a shower head.  The plumber quoted around $40 per screw which was ridiculous.  My local bolt man sold me ten for $3 total.

Comment: actually, it will replacing pedal**s**, because that pair is not original and cannot find the same anywhere. yea normal story for the grub screws, but here the problem is that I didn't expect to be sooo hard to find the same hex nut.

Comment: Sooo far, I went to the 3rd solution, to machinist, It took one day to made it. It made the thread of the spindle with smaller size in order to fit with existing hex nut. The hex nut was larger and was fitting exactly in the hole of the pedal platform and wasn't enough for a tool to rotate the nut. However I've managed to tighten hex nut and now fixed strong. I think now it's impossible to be loosen back again. _But the conclusion I've made from this case is to buy a new pair pedals._